# Ошибки в тестовом примере автотеста Selenium Testing Tools with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

В автоматизации я полный ноль. пытался воспроизвести примеры из Learning Selenium Testing Tools with Python, но у меня возникают следующие ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/projects/Selenium/Python/sample1/searchproducts.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Антон\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 99, in _wait_until_connectable
    "The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Вот код учебного теста:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the application home page
driver.get('http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/')

# get the search textbox
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_field.clear()

# enter search keyword and submit
search_field.send_keys('phones')
search_field.submit()

# get all the anchor elements which have product names displayed
# currently on result page using find_elements_by_xpath method
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")

# get the number of anchor elements found
print ('Found ' + str(len(products)) + ' products:')

# iterate through each anchor element and
# print the text that is name of the product
for product in products:
    print (product.text)

# close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

Гуглеж результата не дал.
Пожалуйста подскажите, что нужно исправить.

Comment: обновить selenium, использовать firefox 45 или ниже

Comment: Вбить "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details." в Google Translate.

Comment: @Nakilon и что? мне это ни о чем не говорит. Я не разбираюсь ни в бинарниках ни в логах. Выше я писал, что в автоматизации ноль.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa спасибо - помогло.

Comment: Очевидно следовало вбить в Google "how to specify a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor". То, что ты ноль, не оправдание нежеланию вчитываться в сообщения об ошибках.